# When testing React, should I checking for React components or HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, mocha.js, enzyme

As an example, I will have a `Toolbar` React component. `Toolbar` contains a `Form` React component that will contain an `input` HTML element. When testing `Toolbar` should I be searching for the existence of a `Form` component or for an `input` element?

I want to say testing should search for HTML elements because the specific components used may change over time, but the HTML elements should stay the say (the point is this `Toolbar` should have a place for input, regardless of whether we're using a `Form` component or an `Input` component or whatever else is made later on).

But on the other hand, reuse is good right? I made the `Form` component as a reusable component for a reason. And in the `Form` component tests I could test for the existence of certain HTML elements, and in  the `Toolbar` tests I could just look for the existence of `Form`, knowing it'll have the `input` I need.

Is there a general best practice of what I should be testing for or does it depend?

Comment: General rule of thumb: it *always* depends. But if you're testing `Toolbar` and `Toolbar` wants a `Form` then that's what the `Toolbar` tests should test for, not the *implementation* of `Form`: that's what the `Form` tests test for.